# Как через try/except определить что строка не содержит цифры?

Tags: python, строки

Всем привет. Придумал(ну почти) себе задачу: пользователь вводит разные слова через пробел, нужно найти и вывести самое длинное слово и количество букв.
Потом встал вопрос, а как можно через try/except ограничить ввод, чтобы если пользователь ввел цифры или цифру с буквой, то программа ему об этом сообщила и попросила исправить.
Если бы наоборот нужно было вводить только цифры, это легко проверить ну к примеру вот так:

```
try:
    int(input('Введите число: '))
except ValueError:
    print('Только число')
```

А вот с буквами возникли сложности. Будьте добры подскажите возможно ли проверить через try/except моё условие или может есть другие способы? Вот сам код задачи.

```
a = input('Введите любые слова через пробел: ').split()
max_length = 0
word = 'tmp'
for i in a:
    if len(i) > max_length:
        max_length = len(i)
        word = i
print(f'Самое длинное слово из введённых: {word}, его длина равна {max_length}')
```

Comment: Не знаю, как это в пайтоне, но в джаве считается неправильным делать бизнес-логику на основе исключений. Потому что исключения предназначены для индикации нештатной ситуации, когда программа не работает так, как надо. То, что пользователь ввёл что-то кроме числа - это не нештатная ситуация для программы, потому что вы можете это обработать как следует.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки, что на вводе находится **целочисленное значение**, не нужно использовать `try-except`. Примените метод `.isdecimal()`, например:

```
while True:
    number = input('Введите число: ').strip()
    if not number.isdecimal():
        print("Неправильный ввод. Ожидается число.")
        continue
    else:
        number = int(number)
        break
```

---

Подобным образом вы можете это сделать для проверки, если на вводе списка слов **не находятся цифры**. Только вместо проверки

```
if not number.isdecimal():
```

примените например

```
import string

for s in word_list:
    if s in string.digits:
```

---

Весь цикл для списка слов:

```
import string

while True:
    word_list = input('Введите слова через пробел: ').strip()
    for s in word_list:
        if s in string.digits:
            print("Неправильный ввод (цифра в нем).")
            break
        continue
    else:
        break;

# Правильный ввод, продолжаем...
```

*Объяснение:*

1. `string.digits` то же самое как строка `"0123456789"`.
2. Первый `break`: для цикла `for` – когда уже плохо, не надо дальше проверять (не будет лучше).
3. `continue`: тоже для цикла `for` – когда еще не плохо, в будущем может быть.
4. Второй `break`: для цикла `while` – всё в порядке, правильный ввод, не надо уже пользователя спрашивать.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный полезный ответ

Comment: @Taron, не стоит. :-)